# How can i take the 0.5 of the folder name?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My folder name is : `east_resized_0.5`
what i want is, if i see the specific word `resized` in the name to take the number after, the number being any in this case `0.5`, could be `7.23` etc..

what i have done is :

```
path_to_east = 'data/east_resized_0.5'
resized = re.findall(r'resized',path_to_east)
if resized:
    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', path_to_east)
    print(numbers)
    resized = numbers[0] +'.'+ numbers [1]
    print(resized)
```

The output will be

```
['0', '5']
0.5
```

which does give me what i want eventually but it's not a clean way to say the least and it'll get even messier when i have to make a while loop to make sure every element is in resized if for example the number is `7.23`.
How can i use regex to make my code cleaner and more efficient

Comment: Use `m = re.search(r'resized_(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)',path_to_east)` and `if m: print(m.group(1))`

Comment: How about not use regex and simply: `r = s.split('resized_')[1:]`. If r exists... `return r[0]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works, wish it wasn't marked as duplicate to be able to accept in bellow.

Comment: Matching numbers is a very well-known issue. If I answer, a lot of people will downvote both your question and my answer.